# Socket using in a swing applet

Tags: java, swing, sockets, web-applications

I should made a server & client in Java,based on Swing and gui.I neeed to make somehow a socket that will go from the server to the client and from the client to the server, and will pass some kind of a string.I would like to have later a function that would do several things according to the string that would be in the socket.
For some reason I couldn't find a simple example for code that shows how it's done in a simple way.
Anyone has any simple example or can explain how is it being done?

Answer (score 23):

Based on this [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.help/msg/9f7f86db103f35c9), here's a simple network client-server pair using Swing. Note some issues related to correct synchronization: The GUI itself is constructed on the event dispatch thread using [`invokeLater()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). In addition, the code relies on the thread safety of [`append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29). Finally, it incorporates a handy tip from the article [*Text Area Scrolling*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/).

Update: In Java 7, [`append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) is no longer marked as thread safe; `invokeLater()` is used in `display()` to sequence updates.

[image]

```
package net;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

/**
 * A simple network client-server pair
 * @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245805
 */
public class Echo implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int PORT = 12345;
    private final JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private final JTextField tf = new JTextField(25);
    private final JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(15, 25);
    private final JButton send = new JButton("Send");
    private volatile PrintWriter out;
    private Scanner in;
    private Thread thread;
    private Kind kind;

    public static enum Kind {

        Client(100, "Trying"), Server(500, "Awaiting");
        private int offset;
        private String activity;

        private Kind(int offset, String activity) {
            this.offset = offset;
            this.activity = activity;
        }
    }

    public Echo(Kind kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
        f.setTitle("Echo " + kind);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(send);
        f.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(ta), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(send, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setLocation(kind.offset, 300);
        f.pack();
        send.addActionListener(this);
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
        ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) ta.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        display(kind.activity + HOST + " on port " + PORT);
        thread = new Thread(this, kind.toString());
    }

    public void start() {
        f.setVisible(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    //@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String s = tf.getText();
        if (out != null) {
            out.println(s);
        }
        display(s);
        tf.setText("");
    }

    //@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket socket;
            if (kind == Kind.Client) {
                socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            } else {
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                socket = ss.accept();
            }
            in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            display("Connected");
            while (true) {
                display(in.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            display(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    private void display(final String s) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            //@Override
            public void run() {
                ta.append(s + "\u23CE\n");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            //@Override
            public void run() {
                new Echo(Kind.Server).start();
                new Echo(Kind.Client).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that reminds me: this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14617650/230513) shows how a server can accept multiple clients.

Comment: I keep seeing code all over the internet that happens to work because it uses Swing methods that happen to be thread-safe (such as setText), and I can't find a good example of how to have a background network thread send events to the EDT :/

Comment: @Nicolás: I usually use [`SwingWorker`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20swingworker%20%5bjava%5d).

Answer (score 2):

A basic example would be this:
(based on tutorial from [*Socket Programming in Java*](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Socket-Programming-in-Java/), by A.P.Rajshekhar)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws
    UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // create the server socket
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(
                    8888, 5, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
                // wait until clients try to connect
                Socket client = server.accept();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                // loop until the connection is closed
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    // output what is received
                    System.out.println(line);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // connect with the server
                Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8888);

                // attach to socket's output stream with auto flush turned on
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

                // send some text
                out.println("Start");
                out.println("End");
                // close the stream
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // start server
    serverThread.start();
    // wait a bit
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // start client
    clientThread.start();
}
```

Comment: But is it possible to transfer data from both sides?  
Because a ServerSocket has no function that equals to what the client is having such as   s.getOutputStream(),then how is it being done?
What I mean is that i need to have conversation that would basic on what you wrote,but how the server would give back hus answer?

Comment: Once the connection is established - both sides are equal. Hence they can both send and receive data