# Use JTextField to List items

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I'm not too familiar with Java GUI programming, and I wanted to do something where I have a loop that spits out a list of stuff and have the JTextField render it in the order it comes out.

I just do not know how the second parameter of the JTextField insert() function works. Right now when I do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    textArea.insert(list.get(i), 0);
}
```

It does what I want, except it lists everything in backwards order that I put it in. I want it to display everything the other way around.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: See also [`Console`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443878/redirecting-system-out-to-jtextpane/4444677#4444677).

Comment: *"Use JTextField to List items"*  No, I'd Use `JList` (or possibly `JTable` or `JTree` depending on the complexity and associations between the items) to List items.

Comment: api doc: "Inserts the specified text at the specified position" - which exact part of that sentence don't you understand?

Comment: btw, you are using a _JTextArea_ , aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to define a temporary string, `result` and for every item in the list add the string representation to that variable. When you have looped through everything, all you need to do is `textArea.setText(result)`.

```
String result = "";    
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    result += list.get(i).toString();
}

textArea.setText(result);
```

Comment: Is this the only way I can do this? I wanted to have a textfield kind of similar to a command line output and have the user be able to make a bunch of the lists etc. This would mean that I would be constantly updating a really long string.

Comment: See [`append()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That one's new to me as well! Looks like I've got some code to edit!