# Run another Java program from within a Java program and get outputs/send inputs

Tags: java, swing, ui-automation

I need a way to run another java application from within my application. I want to recive its outputs into a JTextArea and send it inputs via a JTextBox.

Comment: Do you need to run the entire program? Can you just execute the appropriate Java code from the other code base in your program?

Comment: Do you control the source of the other app.?  What is the other app.? BTW - There is no such thing as a `JTextBox` - please copy/paste these things.

Comment: I need to run and control the entire program and recieve its ouput/send it input

Answer (score 3):

Depends.

You could use a custom `URLClassLoader` to load the second applications jar and call the main classes `main` method directly.  Obviously, the issue there is getting the output from the program ;)

The other solution would be to use a `ProcessBuilder` to launch a java process and read the output via the `InputStream`

The problem here is trying to find the java executable.  In general, if it's in the path you should be fine.

You can have a look at [this](http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/getting-started-with-javas-processbuilder-a-sample-utility-class-to-interact-with-linux-from-java-program/) as a base line example of how to read the inputstream

**UPDATED with Example**

This is my "output" program that produces the output...

```
public class Output {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is a simple test");
        System.out.println("If you can read this");
        System.out.println("Then you are to close");
    }
}
```

This is my "reader" program that reads the input...

```
public class Input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // SPECIAL NOTE
        // The last parameter is the Java program you want to execute
        // Because my program is wrapped up in a jar, I'm executing the Jar
        // the command line is different for executing plain class files
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "../Output/dist/Output.jar");
        pb.redirectErrorStream();

        InputStream is = null;
        try {

            Process process = pb.start();
            is = process.getInputStream();

            int value;
            while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {

                char inChar = (char)value;
                System.out.print(inChar);

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

You can also checkout [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more information

Comment: The problem is that I do have a good understanding of Java but I have no experience with ProcessBuilders or much with InputStreams.. I have used these before but on a side note.. where do you learn more Java? Ive already ready 2 books and watched/read online.

Comment: *"where do you learn more Java?"* Not relevant to this site & you didn't ask me, but I'll venture an answer anyway.  I learn mostly from the Java Tutorials, answers I find on sites like this one, and asking (& answering) questions on this site.  An answer to a question on this site can be quite instructive when your peers point at you and laugh, then describe in excruciating detail, the errors in your answer. ;)

Comment: Yes the answers on this site are very helpful but I need help learning in general. This site is helpful in explaining what to use but not how to use it.

Comment: @Taketheword the single best "beginners" resource [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html), I spent my first 4 weeks when I started my first job reading this site from cover to cover

Comment: +1 for `ProcessBuilder`. See also [`Console`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4444677/230513).