# Pipe connectors using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, pipe

How to implement pipe connectors, like Yahoo pipes, using Java Swing.
Or any other kind of wiring in Java Swing, for that matter.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of using `PipedReader` and `PipedWriter` in java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PipedReader;
import java.io.PipedWriter;
/**
 * @date 1st May, 2011
 * @author sanju.org
 *
 * To demonstrate the use of piped character streams.
 * Example program for piped character stream in java.
 *
 */

public class PipedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        PipedReader reader = new PipedReader();
        PipedWriter writer = new PipedWriter(reader);
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(new ReaderThread(writer));
        Thread writerThread = new Thread(new WriterThread(reader));
        readerThread.start();
        writerThread.start();
    }

}

class ReaderThread implements Runnable{
    PipedWriter writer;
    public ReaderThread(PipedWriter writer){
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void run() {
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        try {
            while (true) {
                //sample implementation reading from console
                //real implementation can be reading from a socket or a file
                //or from server side code
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                writer.write(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class WriterThread implements Runnable{
    PipedReader reader;
    public WriterThread(PipedReader reader){
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                char c;
                while( (c = (char)reader.read()) != -1){
                    //write your business logic here
                    //could be writing into a file
                    //could be processing the date
                    System.out.println(c);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for using yahoo with `PipedReader/Writer` class I guess you'd read their API to connect to url etc

Here is a list of other links relating to `PipedReader` and `PipedWriter` (mix of tutorials and information) that could be of help:

- [Java IO: Pipes](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html)
- [Java IO: PipedReader](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipedreader.html)
- [PipedReader PipedWriter example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/pipedreader-pipedwriter-example) (JavaCodeGeeks exmaple)
- [PipedReader and PipedWriter and thread](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/PipedReaderandPipedWriterandthread.htm) (Java2s example)

As for the Swing side of things, to display the data received from a pipe you would need to use a `TextComponent` like one of these:

- [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
- [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

each have a `setText(...)` which will allow you to set their content

**Reference:**

- http://cleanjava.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/use-of-pipedreader-and-pipedwriter-in-java/

Comment: +1 WOW nice!  Might like to add some info about concurrency in Swing though ;)

Comment: +1 See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4444677/230513).

Comment: @MadProgrammer an trashgod thank you and +1 to both (Pipes are very rare hey?!)