# Where is the actionperfomed() method called?

Tags: java, interface

I'm a Java beginner and now as I come down to work with interfaces, I want to know what really happens. I suppose a good example is the ActionListener interface.

All I know about interfaces is, that it forces you to implement the methods given by the interface. But what I don't get, where the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method is called. And are there any simple examples to show me what happens in the background? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) Oracle tutorial. Keep an eye out for the `actionPerformed` method names.

Comment: Q: Does Shane Voisard's response answer your question?  If you look at his stack traceback, you'll see 1) the Java runtime is always looking for "Events", 2) for each event, it calls "java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent()", 3) which ultimately calls the code (the event hander) you registered with "addActionListener()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a JButton, its superclass `AbstractButton` calls the `actionPerformed` method through the method [`fireActionPerformed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#fireActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)) which is a protected method. If you check the source code you'll see that it constructs an `ActionEvent` object and calls `actionPerformed` using it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want details, log an Exception from inside `ActionListener#actionPerformed`:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ListenerTracer extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); }
        });
    }

    public ListenerTracer() {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Press me");
        b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                Exception e = new Exception();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        add(b1);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("actionListener printstacktrace:\n", 50, 50);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        add(scrollPane);
        Console.redirectOutput(textArea);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ListenerTracer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ListenerTracer contentPane = new ListenerTracer();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class Console implements Runnable {
        JTextArea displayPane;
        BufferedReader reader;

        private Console(JTextArea displayPane, PipedOutputStream pos) {
            this.displayPane = displayPane;
            try {
                PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);
                reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(pis) );
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}
        }

        public void run() {
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    displayPane.append( line + "\n" );
                    displayPane.setCaretPosition(displayPane.getDocument().getLength());
                }
                System.err.println("im here");
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error redirecting output : "+ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static void redirectOutput(JTextArea displayPane) {
            PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
            System.setErr(new PrintStream(pos, true) );
            Console console = new Console(displayPane, pos);
            new Thread(console).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking the "Press Me" button produces this output:

> actionListener printstacktrace: java.lang.Exception   at
>   ListenerTracer$2.actionPerformed(ListenerTracer.java:21)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

I borrowed the console redirect code from [camickr's answer to redirecting-system-out-to-jtextpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443878/redirecting-system-out-to-jtextpane).

Answer (score 0):

That will be called when the user does something.  Click a button, select a menu.  Each one of the `actionListener`s is called for a particular event.  I think right now, you need not worry exactly where it is called, just where, and why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well I know that it is called when the specific element is clicked, I have made little GUIs with swing, and they work. But for me it's hard to comprehend where the specific code is, that invokes actionPerformed(). Is it somewhere in the JButton class?