# Window Focus and TextArea text append

Tags: java, swing

I have a logging window in my application. The messages are written to the JTextArea inside this window.

JFrame
 -> JScrollPane
    -> JTextArea

Code that writes the messages:

```
LogTextArea.append(message + "\n");
```

If I have this log window open, whenever something writes a message to this window, the window automatically gets pushed to the top and focused.

For example, I have a form window open and Im filling out information. A message is written to the log window. When the message is written, the Log window gets focused and I can't type in the form I was filling out anymore.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245805) using [`append()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) that does *not* exhibit this behavior. You might compare it with your own code for differences.