# Avoid sleeping snail in swing unit tests

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing

I want to avoid [sleeping snail](http://www.softwaretestingmagazine.com/knowledge/unit-testing-in-java-a-sleeping-snail/) in my swing unit tests, but I don't see a way to do this with events. Currently I have somethink like

```
WindowWithKeyListener window = new WindowWithKeyListener();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
assertTrue(window.key1pressed());

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
assertTrue(window.key2pressed());
```

This doesn't work without `Thread.sleep()` before the assertions, as the events are to slow. But how could I avoid `Thread.sleep()` here?

Swing Timers cannot be executed in a specific order. What is the best approach for testing here?

Comment: We already use Jemmy, if there exists a good solution, that would be a plus.

Comment: Why not register a listener that does the assertations or maybe use a future and wait for the listeners to finish?

Comment: I don't know if I only misunderstand, but of course I don't want to simply verify the event triggering, `key1pressed` stands for more complex logic that is performed because the event was triggered... A single executor and Futures should work, right. Looks like overkill to me, is there a easier solution? But how do you know know that the assertion Future can be started?

Comment: Well, since you always need to wait until the events are finished you'd have to wait for that situation or synchronize the calls somehow.

Comment: The article cited suggests using a `CountDownLatch` to let separate threads rendezvous; you might get some ideas from the examples shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3588523/230513)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jemmy seems to handle this already

```
org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.ComponentOperator.typeKey(int)
```

seems to do some waiting.