# How is messaging between Java classes best accomplished?

Tags: java, android, swing, netbeans, messaging

I have multiple classes and threads that need to write to a Java Swing JScrollPane. In the Android/Eclipse environment I used android.os.Message. Is there something similar in the NetBeans/Windows environment? Here is where I would like to send the message from:

```
public class PrintStatusTask extends Thread {
    PrintStatusTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private void sendMessage(String s) {
        // TODO: send message to jTextArea
    }
    public void run() {
        ...
        sendMessage("Any message");
        ...
```

Here is an example of writing to the JScrollPane from the JFrame it lives in:

```
public class Controller extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Observer {
    ...
    jTextArea.append(s);    
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing to the pane itself (i.e. changing the data on the view) then the best way is to use a swing worker thread, and execute it later:

```
SwingUtilities.executeLater(myThread);
```

(Syntax might be slightly off - I am doing it from memory)

Comment: The `process()` method of `SwingWorker` runs on the EDT, so no there's need to use `invokeLater()`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: The JScrollPane is updated by a background task in another class, or from the JFrame that it lives in. Writing to the JScrollPane seems ot be responsive, but the background task has a lot to do, which is why it is needed.

Comment: @trashgod you are correct - I forgot about that.  I was thinking of a normal thread.

Comment: @JackN Swing is not thread safe - if you update from a thread other than the UI thread, you can cause problems in the UI.  That is why I am recommending either a SwingWorkerThread or SwingUtilities.invokeLater calls.  We have had to do just what you are talking about - have the work run in a background thread and update the UI when it is finished - and this is considered the appropriate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll second [aperkins'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143969/aperkins) suggestion to use [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) as a more robust, general purpose solution.

In the particular case of [`append()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29): "This method is thread safe, although most Swing methods are not." Here is a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245805) of using the method from another thread.

Comment: I had never read that part - huh.  I have always avoided doing UI updates except on the event dispatch thread as a matter of principle, and to make sure I never hit a problem.  Good to know about append though.