# Java memory game with GUI - String and Array comparison

Tags: java, arrays, string, sockets

I am developing a network game of memory in java. It works (or will work) like this:

A client connects to the server. The server randomly generates 12 values between 1 and 100 and sends these values via a string to the client. The client has a board of 12 cards (toggle buttons). Upon receiving the string of values, the client will populate these values onto the 12 cards. The cards will show the values for 10 seconds. The user will then click the toggle buttons in the correct sequence (i.e. starting from the lowest number to the highest). As a card is toggled, the value of that card is appended to a string. After all 12 cards have been selected, the string will be sent back to the server (i.e. PLAYER\1\2\5\8\20\38...). When the server receives the string, it then compares this to the original string sent. If the client is correct, then that persons score will be increased and the board will be re-generated.

I haven't begun coding this yet, but I envisage the following:

The server puts the integers into an array. That array is converted to a string. The string is sent. Upon arrival at the client, a .split method is used based on the '\' delimiter to put the string into an array. I then need to somehow put random values from within the newly created array onto the cards. In addition, I need to be able to click the cards, retrieve their value and add them to a string.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way of doing this?

Comment: Why dont you just send the data as an int-array?

Answer (score 1):

Using a delimited string on the wire seems reasonable. For inspiration, here's an [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) of using `JToggleButton` for a memory game and an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245805) of using sockets for network communication.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the client generate the randonm numbers and check the results. All you need to pass to the server was the score.

Comment: That's a good point. Except, I need multiple clients so wouldn't it be unfair if clients generated a different board?

Comment: If the boards need to be the same, you can pass the random seed to all the clients.  From that random seed you can create any amount of random numbers and be sure they are the same.  However, if you perform multiple tests and they are genuinely random any unfairness will even out.