# Use GridBagConstraints to update layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

I use GridBagConstraints to update my layout, when a button have been clicked, some input fields will appear.

```
private class EventListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input_panel.removeAll();
               String str = e.getActionCommand();
               System.out.print(str);

               JLabel jl = new JLabel("Label ");
            // Create constraints
               GridBagConstraints textFieldConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
               GridBagConstraints labelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

               labelConstraints.gridx = 0;
               labelConstraints.gridy = 0;

               input_panel.add(jl,textFieldConstraints);
        }
    }
```

This function successfully runs, however, there is a strange problem, when I click the button, it do update, but not show immediately, I must need to resize the window to see it. What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input_panel.add(jl,textFieldConstraints);
input_panel.revalidate(); //try to add this
input_panel.repaint(); // and this
```

Comment: Or better, `revalidate()` followed by `repaint()`

Comment: Edit made. The repaint will be necessary at times, especially if components are removed. @PandaYang: understand that `revalidate()` asks the container layout managers to re-layout their components recursively, and the `repaint()` allows the painting methods to clean up any dirty screen portions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks! I was always wondering about difference of `validate`, `revalidate`, `repaint`.

Comment: @PandaYang: if Nikolay's advice helped you, please "accept" his answer.

Comment: @PandaYang, please, don't forget ;)

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov : Hopefully this thread, [Difference between validate(), revalidate() and invalidate()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9510125/1057230), might be of some interest to you :-)