# JButton multiple commands

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

Please help me to understand how can I make my JButton work multiple times?

As of now I only can replace panel one time for each button click, but need it to be done this way: when user press btnNext I want to change panel, and then after another btnNext press change panel, same applies to btnBack.

Thank you.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class beta1 extends JFrame implements ItemListener, ActionListener {

  private final JButton btnNext, btnBack;
  private JButton btnNext2;
  private JButton btnAbout;
  private final JRadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5, rb6;
  private final JCheckBox chk1, chk2, chk3, chk4, chk5, chk6, chk7, chk8;
  private final JComboBox<String> cboAColor, cboBColor, cboCColor, cboProvinces;
  private final JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel(), southpanel = new JPanel(),
      eastpanel = new JPanel(), westpanel = new JPanel(), centerpanel = new JPanel(),
      northpanel = new JPanel(), centerpanelsouth = new JPanel(), centerpanelnorth = new JPanel(),
      centerpanelcenter = new JPanel();
  private final JLabel label = new JLabel(), label1 = new JLabel(), label2 = new JLabel(),
      label3 = new JLabel(), label4 = new JLabel(), label5 = new JLabel();
  // private JLabel button = new JLabel(), button1 = new JLabel();
  private final ImageIcon imgIcon1 = new ImageIcon("S80.png"), imgIcon2 = new ImageIcon("S60.png"),
      imgIcon3 = new ImageIcon("V60.png"), imgIcon4 = new ImageIcon("XC90.png"),
      imgIcon5 = new ImageIcon("XC70.png"), imgIcon6 = new ImageIcon("XC60.png");
  private final ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("Black Sapphire.png"), img2 = new ImageIcon(
      "Electric Silver.png"), img3 = new ImageIcon("Passion Red.png"), img4 = new ImageIcon(
      "Crystal White Pearl.png");
  private final ImageIcon im1 = new ImageIcon("Black ARTICO Leather.png"), im2 = new ImageIcon(
      "Alpaca Grey ARTICO Leather.png"), im3 = new ImageIcon("Beige ARTICO Leather.png");
  private final ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("Burl Walnut Wood.png"), i2 = new ImageIcon(
      "Dark Ash Wood.png"), i3 = new ImageIcon("Aluminium.png");
  private final JLabel txt1 = new JLabel(), txt2 = new JLabel(), txt3 = new JLabel(),
      txt4 = new JLabel(), txt5 = new JLabel(), txt6 = new JLabel(), txt7 = new JLabel(),
      txt8 = new JLabel(), txt9 = new JLabel(), txt10 = new JLabel(), txt11 = new JLabel();
  private double m, total, total1, ftotal, extra, colors, n1, n2, n3, extra1;
  private final JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
  int i = 1;

  double O = 0;
  double Q = 0;
  double N = 0;
  double NB = 0;
  double M = 0;
  double A = 0;
  double BC = 0;
  double PEI = 0;
  double S = 0;
  double NL = 0;
  double SEL = 0;
  private final Color bcolor = new Color(159, 182, 205);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new beta1();
  }

  public beta1()
  {
    // NEXT
    btnNext = new JButton(">>");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    // BACK
    btnBack = new JButton("<<");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    // RADIOBUTTON//
    rb1 = new JRadioButton("Vovlo S80");
    rb2 = new JRadioButton("Vovlo S60");
    rb3 = new JRadioButton("Vovlo V60");
    rb4 = new JRadioButton("Volvo XC90");
    rb5 = new JRadioButton("Volvo XC70");
    rb6 = new JRadioButton("Volvo XC60");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(rb1);
    group.add(rb2);
    group.add(rb3);
    group.add(rb4);
    group.add(rb5);
    group.add(rb6);

    rb1.addItemListener(this);
    rb2.addItemListener(this);
    rb3.addItemListener(this);
    rb4.addItemListener(this);
    rb5.addItemListener(this);
    rb6.addItemListener(this);
    // END OF RADIOBUTTON//

    // JCOMBOBOXBUTTON//
    String[] aa = { "Black Sapphire", "Electric Silver", "Passion Red [add $200.00]",
        "Crystal White Pearl [add $200.00]" };
    cboAColor = new JComboBox<String>(aa);
    cboAColor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
    cboAColor.addActionListener(this);

    String[] bb = { "Black/Black ARTICO Leather, without additional charge",
        "Alpaca Grey/Alpaca Grey ARTICO Leather, without additional charge",
        "Almond Beige/Cashmere Beige ARTICO Leather [add $350.00]" };
    cboBColor = new JComboBox<String>(bb);
    cboBColor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
    cboBColor.addActionListener(this);

    String[] cc = { "Burl Walnut Wood, without additional charge",
        "Dark Ash Wood, without additional charge", "Aluminum[add $200]" };
    cboCColor = new JComboBox<String>(cc);
    cboCColor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
    cboCColor.addActionListener(this);

    String[] dd = { "Select Province", "Ontario", "Quebeck", "Nova Scotia", "New Brunswick",
        "Manitoba", "British Colombia", "Prince Edward Island", "Saskatchewan", "Alberta",
        "Newfoundland and Labrador" };
    cboProvinces = new JComboBox<String>(dd);
    cboProvinces.addActionListener(this);

    // END OF JCOMBOBOX//

    // JCHECKBOXBUTTON //
    chk1 = new JCheckBox("Climate Package [Add $1,350.00]");
    chk2 = new JCheckBox("Technology Package [Add $1,500.00]");
    chk3 = new JCheckBox("Inscription Package [Add $2,600.00]");
    chk4 = new JCheckBox("19\" BOR Diamond Cut Alloy Wheels [Add $1,250.00]");
    chk5 = new JCheckBox("Blind Spot Information System [Add $800.00]");
    chk6 = new JCheckBox("Active Dual Xenon Headlights with Washers [Add $1,000.00]");
    chk7 = new JCheckBox("Front and Rear Park Assist [Add $600.00]");
    chk8 = new JCheckBox("Apple CarPlay System + Bose Sound System [Add $2400.00]");

    chk1.addItemListener(this);
    chk2.addItemListener(this);
    chk3.addItemListener(this);
    chk4.addItemListener(this);
    chk5.addItemListener(this);
    chk6.addItemListener(this);
    chk7.addItemListener(this);
    chk8.addItemListener(this);
    // END OF JCHECKBOXBUTTON//

    // LABEL IMAGE/TEXT/BORDER

    // EMPTY
    ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon("volvo.png");
    label.setIcon(imgThisImg);
    label.setOpaque(false);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    // /END

    // JRADIOBUTTON NORTH
    northpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    northpanel.add(rb1);
    northpanel.add(rb4);
    northpanel.add(rb5);
    northpanel.add(rb6);
    northpanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    // END

    // JBUTTON SOUTH
    southpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    southpanel.add(btnBack);
    southpanel.add(btnNext);
    southpanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    // END

    // JCOMBOBOXBUTTON WEAST
    westpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 0, 0));
    westpanel.add(cboAColor);
    westpanel.add(cboBColor);
    westpanel.add(cboCColor);
    westpanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    // END

    // JCHECKBOXBUTTON EAST
    eastpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 1, 0, 0));
    eastpanel.add(chk1);
    eastpanel.add(chk2);
    eastpanel.add(chk3);
    eastpanel.add(chk4);
    eastpanel.add(chk5);
    eastpanel.add(chk6);
    eastpanel.add(chk7);
    eastpanel.add(chk8);
    eastpanel.add(txt6);
    eastpanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    // END

    // LABEL CENTER
    centerpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    centerpanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    centerpanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    // END

    // MAIN PANEL
    mainpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainpanel.add(southpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainpanel.add(northpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainpanel.add(centerpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // END

    // frame
    setContentPane(mainpanel);
    setSize(480, 960);
    setTitle("Volvo Store");
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    validate();
  }

  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      if (e.getSource() == btnNext) {
        remove(centerpanel);
        remove(northpanel);
        add(westpanel);
        validate();
      } else if (e.getSource() == btnBack) {
        remove(westpanel);
        add(centerpanel);
        add(northpanel);
        validate();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
  {
    if (e.getSource() == rb1) {
      label.setIcon(imgIcon1);
      centerpanel.add(label);

    } else if (rb4.isSelected()) {
      label.setIcon(imgIcon4);
      centerpanel.add(label);

    } else if (rb5.isSelected()) {
      label.setIcon(imgIcon5);
      centerpanel.add(label);

    } else if (rb6.isSelected()) {
      label.setIcon(imgIcon6);
      centerpanel.add(label);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You realy sould use more classes!

Answer (score 6):

You can change the Button-click action by:
`nextButton.setAction(myAction)` [[doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)]
or by implementing a custom `ActionListener`.

For your MainPanel you can use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

With CardLayout you can do something like this:

```
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(MainPanel.getLayout());
      cl.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `repaint()` after `validate()` each time you press any of your two navigation buttons. Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510125/difference-between-validate-revalidate-and-invalidate-in-swing-gui) for a good explanation of those methods.