# Java JTree truncates my nodes after reloading model and setting selection path

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtree

I have a `JTree` where children are instances of my class inheriting from `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

At the beginning the tree has 10 nodes with two levels. Then I add children into some nodes, using `add()` method in my class. Then I reload my tree model:

```
tree.setModel(root) // root is an instance of my class.
```

The children are added and everything works fine. But a problem appears when I want to set the selection path (expanding added children using `tree.setSelectionPath(path)`). Then most nodes are truncated as if they were too long (I see an ellipsis like node).

How can this problem be solved. After commenting `setSelectionPath(path)` line and expanding the nodes manually, everything works fine.

Comment: The children are added and eveything works fine. But a problem appears when I want to set the selection path - for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for DefaultMutableTreeNode in local variable

Comment: You must notify the model that the underlying structure has changed, then it will repaint the nodes accordingly to their full length. [check this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treemodellistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

After having the same problem with OpenJDK 11, the following fix works for me:

```
tree.expandPath(somePath);
tree.invalidate();
```

The key is `invalidate()` telling Swing that the component has to be laid out again. For more details, see [Difference between validate(), revalidate() and invalidate() in Swing GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510125/difference-between-validate-revalidate-and-invalidate-in-swing-gui).