# JtextArea scrolling text up by one page

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea, jcomponent

I have a **JtextArea**(in a scrollPane) in which i have 20 lines of text.

The display capacity of the textArea is 10 lines.

I need to move the 20 lines of text up by one page leaving a blank screen to type if user press enter.So if user scrolls up he will be able to see the 20 lines.

The functionality is similar to **clear** command in linux which will move all the contents up by one page.

How can i achieve this in **JtextArea**??

Please help.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147768/scroll-jscrollpane-to-bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding \n * 20 times every time the user presses enter.
You can do this by implementing a KeyListener, but some would not agree on using KeyListener, I do not see why not.

```
jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                       jTextArea.append("\n");
            }
        });
```

Comment: if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) wrong, btw ENTER is implemented in JTextArea in API,

Comment: `I do not see why not.` because Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`, which is a higher level API. It is always better to use a higher level API when available so you are not dependent on low level events.