# Can you make a Canvas scroll to the left

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-canvas

So I'm making a basic 2D game, and I'm using paths to move the player to a certain point. I am restricted to a window size of 800 x 600, and I want the path to finish at the X coordinate of 1400. How would I make the canvas scroll along to the left as the path goes continues passed the 800 X point.

Another solution I've thought of would be to make the Path take longer and just have the background scroll to give the illusion of what I am trying to achieve. However I would still prefer the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. You can wrap your canvas in a [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html). Note that you can hide the scrollbars and [scroll the viewport programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147768/scroll-jscrollpane-to-bottom) (for example to keep the player character centered at all times).
2. You can refresh the canvas every time the player moves and render everything relative to a "world origin". Use [g.translate(-world.x,world.y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#translate(int,%20int)) before any other rendering command to do this. Note the negative X coordinate.

Comment: Presumably a [`ScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html), not a `JScrollPane`, since this is a JavaFX question.