# GroupLayout: adding more than 2 rows containing 1 label and 1 textbox each

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I am using the following example from the oracle docs:

```
JComponent panel = ...;
GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
panel.setLayout(layout);

// Turn on automatically adding gaps between components
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

// Turn on automatically creating gaps between components that touch
// the edge of the container and the container.
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

// Create a sequential group for the horizontal axis.

GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

// The sequential group in turn contains two parallel groups.
// One parallel group contains the labels, the other the text fields.
// Putting the labels in a parallel group along the horizontal axis
// positions them at the same x location.
//
// Variable indentation is used to reinforce the level of grouping.
hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
        addComponent(label1).addComponent(label2));
hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
        addComponent(tf1).addComponent(tf2));
layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);

// Create a sequential group for the vertical axis.
GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

// The sequential group contains two parallel groups that align
// the contents along the baseline. The first parallel group contains
// the first label and text field, and the second parallel group contains
// the second label and text field. By using a sequential group
// the labels and text fields are positioned vertically after one another.
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
        addComponent(label1).addComponent(tf1));
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
        addComponent(label2).addComponent(tf2));
layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
```

Here is a link to the site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html

The example is near the top. This is what is supposed to happen:

[image]

"This" being that there is a label with an associate JComponent per row. I would like to extend this to 3, 4, 5... rows. I try to add more rows by adding the following lines:

```
hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
    addComponent(label3).addComponent(label4));
hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
    addComponent(tf3).addComponent(tf4));

vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
        addComponent(label3).addComponent(tf3));
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
        addComponent(label4).addComponent(tf4));
```

This is what I'm getting however:

[image]

I cut it off on the left side but as you can see there are 4 textfields and 4 other components. The textfields should ALWAYS be aligned underneath eachother, as well as the components.

Is there something with `GroupLayout` or `SequentialGroup` that I'm missing, because it seemed very trivial to just add more components the way I did.

Comment: For better help sooner post a valid [mcve]

Comment: `it seemed very trivial` - using GroupLayout is never trivial. Usually only IDE's use it. We can generally create logic groupings of components using different layout managers to achieve a flexible layout. In this case I would suggest a `GridBagLayout` would be easier to create a simple 2 x 2 grid.

Comment: Please **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before adding them to a question. If you had you might have noticed that the [tag:oracle] tag has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Can Components be added to groups in* `GroupLayout` *dynamically?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41924962/230513)