# How to get simple java game into a window(applet)

Tags: java, applet, window

I am working on a very simple text adventure game in Java and I am just wondering how to get it into a window so it will look more like an actual game.  Like could I have someone click on an icon and it pop up with this simple game?  Thank you for your help and I am sorry if I waste your time!

```
//bored programming
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String x = "hey";
    System.out.println("Welcome to adventure game!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Which way do you want to go?:  ");
    x = input.nextLine();
    if (x.equals ("west")){
        System.out.println("You walk towards the forest.");
        west();
    }
    else if (x.equals("east"))
        System.out.println("You go East!");
    else if (x.equals("south"))
        System.out.println("You go South!");
    else if (x.equals("north"))
        System.out.println("You go North!");
    else
        System.out.println("You cannot go that way!!");
    }


    public static void west(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Which way shall you go?");
    String x = input.nextLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think a `(J)Applet` is what would be best for the game, instead look to putting the game into a `JFrame`  (the components shown in the screenshot [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui) are inside a `JFrame`).  Also note that `Scanner` is well suited to getting data from an `InputStream`, but does not mesh well with GUIs like applets *or* frames.  It might be necessary to rethink the approach.  Given you don't already have thousands of lines of code, that should not be a great problem.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JTextArea`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) may be a good starting point. Examples may be found in the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244400/socket-using-in-a-swing-applet/3245805#3245805).

Answer (score 1):

Just Migrate your code to NetBeans IDE.Create a Window and may be a text box and whatever you want and finally pack it to an executable jar.

Comment: The [Java Console](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/console.html) does not redirect `System.in`, but the game _could_ be played on the user's command line.