# Java Swing Chatroom in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, paragraph, chatroom

I am looking for good advises in order to make this chatroom :

[image: Chatroom]

with Java Swing. I have bee trying all the java swing components for 3 days but I still don't know what to choose.

The container will also have to insert JprogressBars for file transfert. That's why I thought the JTextPane would be a good idea. I could add the icon but I don't know how to structure the paragraph as it is on the picture (sorry I am a newby).

Thank you very much in advance for you help.

Best Regards,

Vincent Roye

Comment: Aren't you kind of getting ahead of yourself? Your post is kind of like "I've been reading a book on anatomy for three days; now please tell me how to start doing brain surgery".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244400/socket-using-in-a-swing-applet/3245805#3245805) and a helpful [tutorial](http://www.cn-java.com/download/data/book/socket_chat.pdf). A standards-based approach will involve learning about [XMPP](http://www.google.com/search?q=xmpp).

Comment: I got to do the XMPP part and it's working, I have a problem for the display of the message now

Comment: You're working on an [XMPP client in Java](http://www.google.com/search?q=xmpp+client+java)? Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you are having.