# Thread Safety of JTextArea.append

Tags: java, swing

The java doc says the append method is thread safe. However, I recall that when I tried using the append to the text area from different threads (several months ago), I get jumbled text where thread 1 would append some characters and thread 2 would append some other characters.
So instead of getting STRINGstring in the jtextarea, I get SstTrRINingG.

What differences would there be between:

1. synchronizing the append
2. bottlenecking appends from different threads through a threadpoolexecutor
3. using invokeLater on the EDT

or are they all fine for fixing the issue?
Thanks

Comment: I see the doc says that it's thread safe but it also says, "Please see How to Use Threads for more information."

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: I never see that,  just do not believe, in Java + Unicode (UTF-8/16), can you please post http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [`append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) was thread safe *with respect to the EDT*, [`append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) in Java 7 is not. Appends using [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) will be processed in the order in which they are [enqueued](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html). A critical examination of the other approaches would require an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

All your solutions seem ok to me. Since you will need to use some form of Invoke to update the UI anyway, it's probably best to just use `invokeLater` to avoid any other complications.