# DB recomendation for implementing a chat displayer

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Ive got a JTextArea to display the conversation, and i was wondering whats the best way to store the dynamic conversation, and was wondering if there's a better way (like appending) rather then rewritting the whole string to JTextArea after every mssg sent and recieved.

thanks ahead

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Answer (score 2):

JTextAre has [`append(str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method to append string to it. For chat area it will be good to use [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) instead of JTextArea, cause it allows to draw coloring string and emotions images.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing it in a `Text File`. Storing all the text in database won't be a good idea.

You can for example store the chat in text file called for example  `874658.txt`  then store the name of this file in the database, along with date of the chat and the parties of it.