# Safe to use Component.repaint() outside EDT?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I cannot find any official documentation saying that it is safe to call [`Component.repaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) from another thread than the Event Dispatch Thread, the EDT.

Is this so? And where can I find some documentation/code?

Comment: good question +1, my helicopter views :-) --> `a)` everything works until repaint() isn't locked by Thread.sleep(int), `b)` there were a few topics about isEventDispatchThread(), but those lins are lost on plundered Java.Net `c)` agreed with API for AWT Components and for their nested classes in Swing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a [quote from an official page](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html#exceptions) stating that:

> **The following JComponent methods are safe to call from any thread:** `repaint()`, `revalidate()`,
>   and `invalidate()`. The `repaint()` and `revalidate()` methods queue requests for the
>   event-dispatching thread to call `paint()` and `validate()`, respectively.

**EDIT 1 :**

---

Since the previous link mentioned has been shifted. I am posting a [new link](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/uiswing/painting/concepts.html), though it might take a bit more time to actually know the authenticity of this page, since it appears to be from `Java` though it originated from some `University`'s server, as can be seen from the address bar.

Comment: Both links don't work anymore, and I cannot find the referenced text anywhere :( Also note that the methods are  [not specified to be thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905985/is-the-swing-repaint-method-still-safe-to-use-outside-the-edt-in-java-7) even if they are...

Comment: As the links are obsolete [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html#paint_process) is an updated link. "JComponent.repaint() registers an asynchronous repaint request to the component's RepaintManager, which uses invokeLater() to queue a Runnable to later process the request on the event dispatching thread."

Answer (score 8):

It is thread-safe. The `RepaintManager` ensures that such calls are placed in the Event Dispatch Thread.

[Painting in AWT and Swing ("official" documentation)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#mgr)

> The purpose of Swing's `RepaintManager` class is to maximize the
>   efficiency of repaint processing on a Swing containment hierarchy, and
>   also to implement Swing's 'revalidation' mechanism (the latter will be
>   a subject for a separate article). It implements the repaint mechanism
>   by intercepting all repaint requests on Swing components (so they are
>   no longer processed by the AWT) and maintaining its own state on what
>   needs to be updated (known as "dirty regions"). Finally, it uses
>   `invokeLater()` to process the pending requests on the event
>   dispatching thread, as described in the section on "Repaint
>   Processing" (option B).
>
> For most programs, the RepaintManager can be viewed as part of Swing's
>   internal system and can virtually be ignored. However, its API
>   provides programs the option of gaining finer control over certain
>   aspects of painting.

Comment: Thankx for this wonderful Painting Doc, I needed this stuff for so long :-), just couldn't find it. Seems like I was waiting for you to refer to it :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali: I rely on it, too. One handy way to find it is through the [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) API.

Answer (score 2):

about the experiences on this forum

(+1 for both answerers) but, I think that not possible to answering your question correctly, part of methods `Graphics(2D)` required call for `repaint()` programatically, rest of them implementing this method (in `API`) directly (sure some of them missing this method in API)

for part of `Swing JComponents` is maybe better to dis-agree, this forum is full of questions about `Concurency in Swing`, starting with `Graphics(2D)` thought `JTextComponents`, `JTree`, and ends (same way is declared as thread safe) with `setText()`,

about `Concurency in Swing` are there notable numbers of questions

Comment: ehhh ........ ? The answer to the question is clearly YES - no need to muddy the waters by possibly misbehaving _unrelated_ code

Comment: I'll endorse mKorbel's healthy skepticism: 1) APIs can [change](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513), although probably not `repaint()`. 2) While `repaint()` itself is thread-safe, one typically calls it after updating a component, which _isn't_ thread-safe.

Comment: @trahgod thanks for the translation :-) Though I tend to disagree a bit: a) there was no change, but a fix of a doc error (arguably the same thingy, it was a long story) b) if so, the code _before_ calling repaint is wrong, not the repaint itself

Comment: "about the experience on this forum" is something for [meta], not for answers.