# Using a Java Swing GUI, how can I run a Server Socket in the background and still use the GUI?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have a basic server working but I want to be able to press a button in the GUI to run said server.

Currently, when I press the button to run the server, the button stays pressed and the rest of the GUI is inaccessible until I force stop it in Netbeans. I want to include buttons to stop the server etc so I want to know how I can have the server code run in the background whilst interacting with the GUI for anything else.

How can I achieve this in the GUI?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some code details at the very least.  Otherwise we'll be guessing what a "basic server" is.

Comment: @Andrew EDT == Event Dispatching Thread?

Comment: @Hovercraft  I decide to upgrade that comment to an answer, since it is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: @Gray  Right first time.  Every Swing programmer should be familiar with it, and what it means to program accounting for it.

Comment: Sure @Andrew.  I always answer and comment for posterity and try to be verbose.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far, I'll look into that link Hovercraft :-) Also, when I say 'basic server' it basically receives a file sent from a client before closing.

Comment: @Gray *"I .. try to be verbose."*  When I ***try*** to be verbose in a comment, I generally hit the character limit. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). Run the server on a `Thread`.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

---

Mentioned in a comment, but see also this (very much) related [example of providing a Swing GUI  for a server & client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You should use Thread class for this purpose.
Implement runnable interface in your main class, then override run() method. Put the codes you want them to be done when the button is pressed in run() method. Then in the button ActionListener write this code:

```
new Thread(this).start();
```

This will execute the code in a different 'thread'.

Comment: I think your advice has some weaknesses as it reduces class cohesion and increases coupling. The GUI class should not also be the Runnable class as the socket code should be in a separate class and should be totally ignorant about all GUI code. Also better to use a SwingWorker rather than a plain Thread since the SwingWorker has tools that allow interaction and communication with the Swing thread  that Thread doesn't have.

Comment: I just wanted to provide him with a fast solution for overcoming his problem; in a greater scale and bigger project yes you are right. This solution is not a good one!

Comment: my view, I think that this is OP's issue, I'd suggest to edit with real answer about EDT, better coud be to delete that