# JAVA - Socket.accept() freezes ui

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I'm trying to make a multithreaded server/client app with java ! this code is for listen() method in a class of a package that named Bsocket (iserver.core.socket) :

```
 try {
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
 }catch(IOException e ){
     ui.log(e.toString());//*
 }
while (true){
    try{
        clienSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        ui.log("Incomming Connection.");//*
        new connectionHandler(clienSocket, ui);
    }catch(IOException e ){
        ui.log(e.toString());
    }
}
```

`ui.log("Incomming Connection.");` is a method in below of main class of Bgui (iserver.core.ui).Bgui is a jframe that contain a textarea and something else ! the problem is when the accept methods executed , the `ui.log` did not works ! whats wrong here ?

Comment: The Question is fully informed !!! but some info's is optinal ! you like -1 huh ? :) ok ! look at `dty` answer!

Comment: You should have a look at this [tutorial about SwingWorkers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Heh, I undid the -1 once I figured out that you didn't know about how UI systems worked.  I got confused by your talking about log output and jframes.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate UI threads from your own network service threads. accept() is blocking (obviously) and it freezes your application until you get a new client, and freezes again waiting for more clients.

Comment: can you tell me more about separating this layers ?

Comment: this is a short question with a really large response. you need to learn some concepts about concurrency. it is very important developing UI applications. Oracle provides some interesting [tutorials related to concurrency in Swing applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't "freeze your application", it just blocks the single thread that calls it. All other threads are free to do their own thing.

Comment: @dty your response is true. the application freezes as a consequence of blocking the UI thread with socket.accept() method.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to launch your server on a seperate thread since `.accept` is a blocking call. You might want to do something like so:

```
(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         try {
              serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
          }catch(IOException e ){
              ui.log(e.toString());//*
          }
         while (true){
             try{
                 clienSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                 ui.log("Incomming Connection.");//*
                 new connectionHandler(clienSocket, ui);
             }catch(IOException e ){
                 ui.log(e.toString());
             }
         }
    }
}).start();
```

NOTE: This code is not tested, but it should give you an idea of what you need to do.

Answer (score 7):

`Socket.accept()` blocks until there's an incoming connection to receive (see the documentation). You shouldn't be making any blocking calls from your UI thread - otherwise it will... you know... block!