# How to view paragraph symbol in JTextPane using Java Code?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jtextpane, japplet

How can I view a [*pilcrow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow), ¶, in a `JTextPane` using Java? Please adivise me or send me any sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this http://java-sl.com/showpar.html

Comment: Good example; good choice. Also consider "\u23CE", illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513); +1 from earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Insert a [*pilcrow*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b6/index.htm) in your `JTextArea`. For example,

```
textArea.append("\u00B6");
```