# Java - Threads, Swing, and ServerSocket

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, client-server

I know I know, already a million questions and answers on this everywhere. Tons of really detailed articles on it, several types of examples. I've spent the past few hours reading about it, but that's not doing the trick. The reason I'm asking this is because I still don't quiet understand what I need to do apparently because my code is still not working. I get the idea of how Swing works with the EDT, and if I'm going to use the ServerSocket's accept() method I'm going to need to start a new thread for Swing (I think?). When I run my code as it is the window just opens and freezes. **My question is could someone look at my code, tell me what I'm doing wrong, and explain it to me like I only have half a brain?**(Because that's what I feels like. :P )

Here are some of the places I've read already:

- [This question from SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244400/socket-using-in-a-swing-applet)
- [This site.](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/swing_ui.shtml)
- [And of course the Oracle's explanation of swing and threads.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- And a few other random sites.

***Main.class***

```
package com.sever.core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main { 

private SocketManager network;
public static void main(String[] args){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Window window = new Window();
            window.setVisible(true);
        }       
    });

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.run();
        }       
    });     


}

public void run(){
    network = new SocketManager(25595);

    while(true){
        try {
            network.setSocket(network.getServerSocket().accept());
            AddUser(network.getSocket());
            Thread x = new Thread(network);
            x.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect.");
        }
    }

}

public void AddUser(Socket s){
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        network.addUser(input.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
}
```

***Window.class***

```
package com.sever.core;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{

private int screenWidth = 800;
private int screenHeight = 600;
private Thread thread;

private JPanel window = new JPanel();
private JTextArea consle = new JTextArea("Server started....");
private JTextField input = new JTextField();
private JScrollPane consleinput = new JScrollPane(consle);

public Window(){
    this.setName("NAMEHERE - Server Software");
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(screenWidth,screenHeight);  
    window.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    window.setLayout(new BoxLayout(window, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    consleSetup();
    addComponets();
}

private void addComponets(){
    add(window);
    window.add(consleinput);
    window.add(input);
}

private void consleSetup(){
    consle.setEditable(false);
    consle.setLineWrap(true);
    consle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3,3,3,3)); 
    consleinput.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    input.setMaximumSize(new             Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,input.getPreferredSize().height));
}

private void addListeners(){
    input.addActionListener(new ActLis());
    input.setActionCommand("input");
}

}
```

***SocketManager.class***

```
package com.sever.core;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SocketManager implements Runnable{

private Socket sock;
private ServerSocket sersoc;
private PrintWriter output;
private BufferedReader input;
private Thread thread;

public ArrayList<Socket> currentConnections = new ArrayList<Socket>();
public ArrayList<String> currentUsers = new ArrayList<String>();


public SocketManager(String ip, int port){
    try{
        sock = new Socket(ip,port);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Server: socket started.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Server: Socket failed to connect.\n");
    }
}

public SocketManager(int port){
    try {
        sersoc = new ServerSocket(port);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Server: Socket failed to connect.\n");
    }
}

public SocketManager(Socket socket){
    this.sock = socket;

    try{
        output = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public synchronized void checkConnetion(){
    if(!sock.isConnected()){
        for(int x = 0; x <= currentConnections.size(); x++){
            if(currentConnections.get(x) == sock){
                currentConnections.remove(x);
                System.out.println("Server: Disconnecting from: " + currentConnections.get(x) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

public synchronized Socket getSocket(){
    return sock;
}

public synchronized ServerSocket getServerSocket(){
    return sersoc;
}

public synchronized void setSocket(Socket s){
    System.out.println("Setting socket to: " + s.getInetAddress());
    sock = s;
}

public synchronized void addSocket(Socket s){
    currentConnections.add(s);
}

public synchronized void addUser(String u){
    currentUsers.add(u);
}

public synchronized ArrayList<Socket> getConnections(){
    return currentConnections;
}

public synchronized ArrayList<String> getUsers(){
    return currentUsers;
}

public synchronized void send(String data){
    try{
        output.println(data);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public synchronized void close(){
    try{
        sock.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    output = null;
    input = null;
    System.gc();
}

public synchronized boolean isConnected(){
    return (sock == null) ? false : (sock.isConnected() && !sock.isClosed());
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Is runing.");
    while(true){
        try {
            checkConnetion();
            if(input.readLine().isEmpty()){ 
                return;
            }

            output.println("Server: Recived your message.");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally{
            try {
                sock.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

***ActLis.class***

```
package com.sever.core;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ActLis implements ActionListener{

private JTextField actionField;
public ActLis(){

}

public ActLis(JTextField t){
    actionField = t;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    if(cmd == "input"){

    }
}

}
```

**--EDIT---**
The new Main.class with SwingWorker

```
package com.sever.core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Main { 

private SocketManager network;
public static void main(String[] args){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Window window = new Window();
            window.setVisible(true);
        }       
    });

    SwingWorker server = new SwingWorker(){
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.run();
            return null;
        }

    };
    server.run();

}

public void run(){
    network = new SocketManager(25595);

    while(true){
        try {
            network.setSocket(network.getServerSocket().accept());
            AddUser(network.getSocket());
            Thread x = new Thread(network);
            x.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect.");
        }
    }

}

public void AddUser(Socket s){
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        network.addUser(input.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your socket is running on the EDT, since you use invokeLater. You should execute Main.run(), using a SwingWorker.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Alright, thanks. I read about that, but when I did I wasn't sure if that's what I wanted. I'll give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are reading from your Socket on the EDT. This means that you block it. Calling invokeLater only causes your Runnable to be executed on the EDT. You are piling two calls on the EDT, one of them being your socket.

Consider moving your socket in a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) which returns progressively the values of your Socker to the GUI.

Comment: Alright, I've done that. It works without freezing now, but now for some reason accept() is still not running. I edited my question and added my changed with a SwingWorker at the bottom.

Comment: @Zexanima You are calling run() instead of execute() on your SwingWorker. Bu that's not the only problem, don't create a Thread inside your Main.run(), SwingWorker will create that Thread for you. Finally, don't return null, but return the input coming from your Socket. Also, add the missing types <T,V> of SwingWorker<T,V>, this will be cleaner.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Why would I return the input of  my socket though? I'm not going to use it's return (As far as I know.) so is it to just make my code cleaner?

Comment: @Zexanima you can then override the process() method and use the output of your socket to update your GUI because process is run on the EDT.

Comment: That makes sense and actually answers another questions I've been trying to figure out, how to get my information from my socket to update my GUI. Thanks a ton, you've really helped me a lot. Probably wont be my last question regarding this though. :)

Comment: @Zexanima all this is available in the JavaDoc of SwingWorker. Take a lookt at their example with PrimeNumbersTask. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Socket operations block. For instance, if you call `accept`, the call will not return until someone actually connects to your program, effectively *blocking* the thread it's running on. That's why they suggest to have the networking run on a secondary thread.

In your case, you do create a thread, but you don't call `accept` from it.

```
while(true) {
    try {
        // this is called on the EDT--beware!
        network.setSocket(network.getServerSocket().accept());
        AddUser(network.getSocket());
        // ... and then, everything called from x will be on the secondary thread
        Thread x = new Thread(network);
        x.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to connect.");
    }
}
```

This is why it freezes. The call to `accept` must be done from the secondary thread if you don't want to block the UI.

Comment: He's calling `accept` inside of a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` right?  That is not in the "main thread" but is in the AWT dispatcher thread.  His program is "freezing" because he is blocking the AWT dispatcher thread from running with the accept.

Comment: @Gray, that's right, I guess. I call the "main thread" whichever thread gets the most action. I'll edit that.

Comment: That's incorrect terminology IMO.  The main thread in my language is the thread that calls `static void main()`.

Comment: Well you edited your post dude.  You had the term "main thread" in there before.