# Refreshing a JList after adding element from another Frame

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist

I'm having an urgent issue concerning the refresh of the JLists. Been looking for some days, didn't found and forget to search further >< and now I'm in a hurry with it.

I'll try to explain it in detail:

1. I open a Java frame1 and a JList is shown. Jlist is feed by a string array that is read from disk.
2. I open a new frame2 which is created by frame1
3. I add new element to the string array that feeds the JList in frame2. Element is saved in a file disk.
4. I close the frame2. I'm again in frame1.

Then my question is, there's any method or way to refresh the jframe1 JList in order to show the new element added?

Thanks in advance, if you need a more detailled description of the steps I'll post it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I'd use a modal dialog, and refresh the main frame the code line after `dialog.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: +1 simple and direct; also consider the _observer pattern_, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).