# JTextField with styled blocks

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, styleddocument

I need some kind of JTextField that replace carriage return characters by a styled block displaying the text <New Line> with another font, style or color.

By example, the text..

```
Dear Mr. Smith,\nblablabla...\nRegards...
```

..would be shown to the user, in a one line JTextField, this way :

> **Dear Mr. Smith,***<New Line>***blablabla...***<New Line>***Regards...**

These <New Line> should be blocks that are selectable as if it was a single character and could be deleted with a single backspace. Pressing the return key would add a <New Line> at the caret position.

I think it can be possible by overriding `PlainDocument`, but I'm stuck in difficult to understand Document and EditorKit APIs. I would need some pointers about this one...

I do not have any objection using a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` as long as it behaves like a `JTextField` (one line, no scroll-bars).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any suggestions ?

Use a `JTextArea` (a multi-line component) instead.

For an example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244400/socket-using-in-a-swing-applet/3245805#3245805):

[image]

---

> It would be simpler, but this is not what I have to do...

Fair enough, I missed the part that stated:

> ..with another font, style or color.

That would require a styled document such as `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`.

Comment: Yes Andrew, it needs to be presented that way. I do not have any objection using a JTextPane or JEditorPane as long as it behave like a JTextField (one line, no scrollbars).

Comment: Interesting trick @trashgod, maybe by replacing carriage returns by this unicode character, and convert them back, it may provide an acceptable workaround.

Comment: I edited part of your comment back into the question.  I am not sure if @trashgod would be notified of the comment without the `@`.

Comment: To have different `Font, Style or Colour` for each `String Literal`, you are bound to look towards `JEditorPane/JTextPane`. THough how you want the `newline` to be displayed, it's the area of logic, You want to know that as an answer, or you already found one ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: For reference, I saw your ping, but not that of François Cassistat; I'm not sure [why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/163188). Please don't hesitate to cite my example in the `JTextArea` part of the answer.

Comment: @trashgod  I'm surprised I missed that opportunity (now rectified) to throw a good screenshot into the answer.  :P

Comment: @trashgod ..and where did get those ***shoes?*** (with apologies to Johnny from 'Airport'/'Flying High')  One of the few occasions when two frames actually makes sense - though they would typically be on different screens.  ;)