# Minor glitch in the code

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, actionlistener, jfilechooser

**The below code is used to create a line graph. I am able to display the integers in the TextArea but i am not able to display the sentences above the integers in the text file. How do i rectify this program?**

The screenshot of the text file is given below.

I want the first three lines of the text file also to be printed in the TextArea.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;   
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.*;
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;

public class Pio {
  static JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Graph");
      static String URL = null;
      static JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
      static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   JButton but = new JButton("Open file");

    ![enter image description here][2]

    panel.add(but);    


    frame1.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);

   frame1.setVisible(true);

frame1.setSize(1000,400);

    but.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

                        {


                         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 

                         {



                         JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

                         int ret = chooser.showDialog(null, "Open file");

                         if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)

                           {

                             File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

                             URL = file.getAbsolutePath();

                           }

                         File f = new File(URL);

                            FileReader inputF = null;

                        try {

                    inputF = new FileReader(f);

                           }
                            catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                                                                e1.printStackTrace();

                                                 }

                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputF);

                             int[] a = new int[100];

                                       int[] b = new int[100];

                                        String s=null;
                    try {

                                       s = in.readLine();

                                    } 

                                 catch (IOException e1) {

                                     e1.printStackTrace();

                                    }

                               int i = 0;

                             while (s != null && i < 100)

                                            { // your arrays can only hold 1000 ints

                                        String pair[] = s.split(" ");

                                        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[0]);

                                        b[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);

                                            i++; // don't forget to increment

                                            try {

                                                s = in.readLine();

                                            }

                                          catch (IOException e1) {
                                                                                  e1.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                            try {

                                in.close();

                                    } 

                                      catch (IOException e1) {
                                                                           e1.printStackTrace();

                                }

                        System.out.println("the output of the file is " + f);

                            XYSeries data = new XYSeries("Line Graph");

                            int n = a.length;

                            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

                                    data.add(a[j], b[j]);

                            }

                            XYDataset xY = new XYSeriesCollection(data);

                                 JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(

                                      "line graph",

                                            "Cycles",

                                           "Temperature",

                                                xY,

                                           PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,

                                           true,

                                          true,

                                           true);

                               ChartPanel p=new ChartPanel(chart);

                                p.setVisible(true);

                                p.setLocation(100,100);

                                p.setSize(500,500);

                              frame1.add(p,BorderLayout.EAST);

                                         }
                        });
            }

}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to include all that file loading/parsing code in your question ? You basically want to combine a `JFreeChart` (or a `ChartPanel`) with a `JTextArea`, and you post a lot of code which has nothing to do with that question

Comment: @Robin I thought it would be easy to understand. I want to place the frame to place all the components on it.

Comment: *"thought it would be easy to understand"*  2 x ASCII art (or simple drawing) of the GUI is easy to understand.  The 1st should show the GUI at minimum size, the 2nd should show it with extra width & height - to illustrate where extra space is assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two display two componenets you can use a JSplitPane.

While loading data into your array append it to a JTextArea (area1 in the sample code)

```
final JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea();
...
area1.append("X=" + a[i] + " Y=" + b[i] + "\n");
```

Then rather than adding the chart to the frame add both the Chart and the TextArea to the JSplitPane

```
ChartPanel p = new ChartPanel(chart);
JSplitPane splitpane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
frame1.add( splitpane , BorderLayout.CENTER );
splitpane.add(p);
splitpane.add(area1);
pane.validate();
frame1.validate();
frame1.repaint();
```

[image: JSplitPane in use]

To append data the the JTextArea use

```
  area1.append("Creating a line graph\n");
  area1.append("Selected file " + f + "\n");
  while (s != null && i < 100) { // your arrays can only hold 1000 ints
    String pair[] = s.split(" ");
    try{
      a[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[0]);
      b[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);
      area1.append("X=" + a[i] + " Y=" + b[i] + "\n");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       area1.append(s + "\n");
    }
    try {
      s = in.readLine();
      i++; // don't forget to increment
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  area1.append("Finished reading data\n");
  ...
```

In this example I'm assuming that the headder will fail `parseInt` and (if is does) appending the String `s`.

[image: JTextArea]

Comment: How do I also print some lines of text in the TextArea before the **X** and **Y** values?

Comment: @user1448671: use `append()`.

Comment: @trashgod The Above screenshot is exactly how it looks. But along with **X** and **Y** values. I want to print a few sentences from the same text file before the **X** and **Y** values.

Comment: @user1448671: Sorry if I'm overlooking something, but you can call `append()` repeatedly, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: @GrahamA I want the sentences before the integer columns in the text file to be printed in the TextArea. How do I do that?

Comment: @user1448671 if you could mock up the layout you would like and add it to your origional question I'll try to ammend my example for you

Comment: @GrahamA I want in the the above format. I want a few lines to be printed in the TextArea before the integers get printed. I have to specify what has to be printed while using append.

Comment: @user1448671 did you try the code I have included in the above example?  I'm using a 'try ... catch' to read a headder from the data file

Answer (score 4):

1. there nothing about `JTextArea`, use constructor [JTextArea(int rows, int columns)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29)
2. put `JTextArea` to the `JScrollPane`, this `JScrollPane` put or the `EAST` or `WEST` area
3. put `JPanel` with `JButton` to the `SOUTH` or `NORTH` area
4. if `ChartPanel` doesn't returns any `PrefferedSize` (I doubt that), or this value isn't correct, then set for own `PrefferedSize`, put `ChartPanel` to the `CENTER` area
5. as you saw there any code line about `setSize`, `JFrame` has implemented `BorderLayout` in the API
6. use `pack()` instead of `setSize()`
7. `setLocation()` if required
8. last code lines in the `ActionListener` (your code logics) must be

   frame.validate();
   frame.repaint();
   frame.pack();
9. in this form (your code logics) is `Swing GUI` during `FileIO` unresponsible for `Mouse and Key Events`, wrap `FileIO` to the `Runnable#Tread` or use `SwingWorker` for redirecting this long and hard task to the background task
10. create `ChartPanel` as local variable (as `JFram`e) and first code line in the `ActionListener` must be

.

```
frame.remove(ChartPanel);
```