# Basic Java Swing JFrame Repainting

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint

New to Swing, but not to Java. I am trying the following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

methodA();
pane.repaint();
methodB();
pane.repaint();

}
```

Where methodB() takes a long time. I would like it to paint twice, yet the first paint call never happens. It's as if I did:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

methodA();
methodB();
pane.repaint();

}
```

Sorry if this is basic, but I've tried searching and I still don't understand why.

I've tried calling paint directly, which works as intended, except the application flickers on every repaint.

Comment: Different scenario, different calls, but same behaviour and same solution: [Java swing GUI freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185485/java-swing-gui-freezes)

Comment: `repaint()` is a request to paint the component _soon_ (not immediately). But if `methodB` takes a long time, it will hold up the event dispatch thread and nothing will get repainted until it is finished. Consider running `methodB` in another thread.

Answer (score 4):

`actionPerformed` is called in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which is also where the painting is executed, `repaint` only flags the component to be repainted. That means that the painting only can be done after `actinPerformed` finishes executing.

Long running tasks should not be executed in the EDT, use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or another Thread.

Indicated to study [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)!