# Java SwingUtilities.invokeLater update TextArea

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

I have the following classes:

- MainServer
- TCPServer
- UDPServer

I create new instances of TCPServer and UDPServer classes (start) from MainServer class, where my GUI is initialized.
In this GUI I have a **textArea**, which either TCP or UDP classes needs to update to display log information (errors, status, etc). I did some search and I know i may need to use EDT in MainServer, but dont know how to access this object in MainServer class from TCPServer or UDPServer. Right now I can only print to console which is undesirable.
How to access MainServer.printlog from TCPServer? or Mainserver.textArea object?
If I create a new MainServer instance from TCPServer or UDPServer this seems not to be working.

This is my function in MainServer class:

```
public void printLog (final String log, final int level) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
    new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
        if (level == 1) 
            textArea.append("INFO\t" + log);
        if (level == 2)
            textArea.append("WARN\t" + log);
        if (level == 3)
            textArea.append("ERROR\t" + log);
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Edit: I tried to create a new instance of `MainServer` and access `printLog` but I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MultithreadedBarcodeReader.MultithreadedBarcodeReaderServer$2.run(
        MultithreadedBarcodeReaderServer.java:68)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
```

Comment: This part looks OK; for reference, there's a working example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: As you state that “this seems not to be working”, please be more precise as to *what* the actual *problem* is you're observing.

Comment: Hi MvG, I have 6 different class files: *MainServerInit, * MainServer, *TCPServer *UPDServer *Decode *Result. In Decode and Result I process anything I obtain from my clients. But the MainServerInit class initialized MainServer which starts the GUI and contains the printLog method. At this stage as I initialized a MainServer instance which also starts TCP and UDP servers, I'm not sure which methods or the sintaxis to access MainServer server = new MainServer; server.printLog("TCP Server() Error",2); from TCP, UDP, Decode, etc.

Comment: Please don't put code or exception output into code comments.  Edit it into the question (as already done by @trashgod).

Comment: Are you sure your "textArea" variable has been initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a separate logging frame-work, or at least a separate logging class with static methods (or a logging factory with static methods). For your application, it should't matter whether they log to the console, to a `JTextArea`, ... and you certainly do not want to pass the `MainServer` instance around only for logging purposes.

Then your application can simply 'log' those messages, and if you want to display those on a certain `JTextArea`, you can simply add a handler which does exactly this. This handler can then be created in the same location as where you create the actual `JTextArea`, and of course can `append` the log messages on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Other advantages of using a decent logging framework are that you can activate the logging on a per-class basis, configure the logging level on a per-class basis, ... and all that without making any changes to your code. So this allows to gather "debug-information" from a deployed application (perhaps even information you do not want to appear in the `JTextArea` but you want to know to diagnostic a problem).

Answer (score 2):

The `NullPointerException` occurs on line 68 in an anonymous class nested in `MultithreadedBarcodeReaderServer`, presumably the `Runnable` cited. One may guess that `textArea` is `null`, as `log` is not dereferenced and `level` is primitive. You'll need to break near that line in the debugger to be certain. Also verify that your GUI components are constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).