# not able to show data in a jTextField

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jtextfield, event-dispatch-thread

I am writing a socket programming. It has GUI for server and client. In the server GUI there is a textfield which shows the word requested by user.
But I am having problem in showing the word.

I have tried

```
txtWord.setText(sentword);
```

It is not showing the word in the textfield. But when I write this

```
txtWord.setText(sentword);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the requesed word is: "+sentword);
```

then it shows the word in textfield and also shows it in the messagebox.

I have tried repaint() but it dint work.
Please suggest me some solution as soon as possible

Comment: Are you performing all operations on one thread? If so, you need to move all none-UI operations to different threads, otherwise you are blocking the UI thread, and you won't see UI updates. It seems like the case, as in your second example you do see the word, as the blocking operation is a UI operation, which not returning to your thread, but keeps updating the UI.

Answer (score 9):

as `@Binyamin` Sharet correctly commented, you have a [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) issue.

- your `Swing GUI` doesn't care about long and hard tasks you're running in the background
- even `JTextField#setText()` is declared as thread safe, output from `Socket` (i.e.) by default never notified [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- correct way could be to use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) that has been created specifically to run long and hard tasks background to the Swing GUI and output to the GUI on event thread or EDT
- or even easier is to use a `Runnable` in a `Thread` but making sure that all output to the `Swing GUI` is queued on the Swing event thread by placing it in a Runnable and calling it with `invokeLater()`
- A dirty hack is to wrap code lines like so:

```
txtWord.setText(sentword);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the requesed word is: "+sentword);
```

into `invokeLater()`, but in this case your GUI will be unresponsive to `Mouse` or `Keyboard` events until `Socket` (in your case) ended

Comment: Sadly, [`setText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) is no longer thread-safe in Java 7; see also [`Echo`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Answer (score -1):

**txtWord.requestFocus();**
textField does not show up until the window is over the textField and back or it gains focus, until Clicking on it. So... just request focus.

Also if check the text size if you had set while creation.Sometimes text not displayed if there is mismatch in size
eg: txtWord.setSize(200, 24);

Comment: -1 You wouldn't need a call to `setBounds` with a `LayoutManager`. And whether or not the textfield has the focus, calling `setText` should place the text inside the textfield

Comment: `setSize` is not needed either when using a `LayoutManager`. All sizing and positioning is done by the `LayoutManager`

Comment: Call `in/re/validate` on the parent container instead of `setBounds/Size` etc.