# JTextPane text not updatng probably from scope issues

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, oop, sockets

I am trying to change the contents of a JTextPane. I think the problem is scope issues.  You can't compile this code but you get the idea... This may be a tough one because of the multi-threading.  TYIA

```
C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui15\src\inigui13.java:259: error: local
variable theframe is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                    theframe.mainfield.getStyledDocumemt().insertString(1, "hellooo",
null);
                    ^ C:\ucdhb2\gaia\inigui\inigui15\src\inigui13.java:259: error: cannot
find symbol
                    theframe.mainfield.getStyledDocumemt().insertString(1, "hellooo",
null);
                                      ^   symbol:   method getStyledDocumemt()   location: variable mainfield of type JTextField
2 errors
```

### Code

```
   class inigui13 extends applet  {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        JTextField mainfield;

      public void init() { 

        inigui13 theframe = new inigui13(); 
        theframe.setSize(700, 525); 
        theframe.setVisible(true); 

        try {

            echoSocket = new Socket("192.168.2.3",  9900);
                        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( echoSocket.getInputStream() ) );
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            System.err.println("Sstemexit");
            System.exit(1);

        } catch (IOException e) {

                System.err.println("IOFailed");
                System.exit(1);
        }


        Runnable readsock = new Runnable()  {

            public void run()   {

                boolean recvread = true;

                while( recvread )   {

                    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                    try {


                    theframe.mainfield.getStyledDocumemt().insertString(1, "hellooo", null);

                    } catch( IOException e ){}

                }

                  }

                    try {

                        out.close();
                        in.close();
                        echoSocket.close();
                    } catch( IOException e ){}


        }

        };


        Thread readsockt = new Thread(readsock);
        readsockt.start();
       }


       public inigui13  {

          mainfield = new JTextPane;
          this.add(mainfield);
      }
};
       }
```

Comment: That code makes no sense.  You open and close socket, but never use it?  You use a `JTextField` in the example, but reference a `JTextPane` in the question (and try and use `getStyleDocument` on a `JTextField`??).  We'll be lucky if we can actually even get you close to solving your problem with that :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not, **EVER**, update, change or modify **ANY** UI component from any thread **OTHER** then the **Event Dispatching Thread**.  This just about covers the first 10 commandments of Swing.

You code is a classic example of when to use a `SwingWorker`.

You might like to have read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

**Example**

```
public class StreamReaderWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, String> {

    private JTextPane field;

    public StreamReaderWorker(JTextPane field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String chunk : chunks) {
            try {
                field.getStyledDocument().insertString(1, "chunk", null);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        boolean recvread = true;
        while (recvread) {
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                publish("hellooo");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm self-taught (for now) I will read through that URL ty

Comment: Also consider `JTextArea`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: I never cease to enojy the Java trails

Comment: @RolandSams I taught my self Java and Swing off those trails for my first job :D

Comment: A question, My socket and writer/reader objects are in the inigi13 class.  How would I get my textpane into the new class?  Should I create new ones?

Comment: hmm, that was a few questions

Comment: You could create the socket as part of the `doInBackground` method of the `SwingWorker`