# tool to view test.h2.db (H2 database)

Tags: sql, database, h2

My java code is using `h2 database` and generating `test.h2.db` file.
I searched online but couldn't find any tool to import this **DB** file and look what are the tables are available in that **DB file**.

I tried `DbVisulizer` but couldn't import this **DB** file.

*If any one worked or faced the same problem, please let me know the solution.*

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Example could be Squirrel.

Comment: Any Java/JDBC based tool can do that - including DbVisualizer

Answer (score 3):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14313923/230513), you can use the `Shell` command to open the database file. In the example below, the database is named `test` and the database file name `test.h2.db` is inferred. As noted [here](http://database%20file), the `url` specifies that the database file resides in the user's home directory.

```
$ java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url \
    "jdbc:h2:file:~/test;ifexists=true" -user "sa" -password ""
```

At the prompt, type `?` for help or enter SQL commands:

```
sql> show tables;
TABLE_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA
CUSTOMER   | PUBLIC
…
```

Note that the schema may be empty if you previously neglected the `ifexists` predicate.

Comment: This kept crashing the container I was trying to run it in with exit code 137, but adding `-Xmx64m` fixed that. I think it was trying to use a bunch of RAM by default, but—at least for basic queries—it can run ok with very little.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the H2 DB installation.

You need to:

- install the H2 DB (for example: h2-setup-2019-10-14.exe),
- go to folder where you install the H2 DB (for example: \H2\bin)
- run the H2 DB (launch the file: h2.bat)
- you should see the Console H2 in the browser (or use the url in browser: http://localhost:8082/
- in Console H2 set option:

  - Genercic H2 (Embedded)
  - Genercic H2 (Embedded)
  - Driver: org.h2.Driver
  - JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:D:/Java/H@_DB/db/repository.mv.db (appropriate path in your disk where is the file )
  - User:
  - Password: