# Access an object from another class

Tags: java, string, swing, class, jtextarea

I have a few classes and one main method. The program is used to connect to an Access database and retrieve information.

I have a class which deals with the GUI only (to display the results) in one    `JTextArea`    box. Another class runs a    `while`    loop and pulls in data from the database and assigns it to a    String    as such:

`line = (line+upid+"\t"+StreetNum+"\t"+suburb+"\t"+area+"\t"+price+"\t"+agentID+"\t"+numBeds+"\t"+numBaths+"\t"+spool+"\t"+numGarages+"\t"+date+"\t"+ownerID+"\t"+SaleOrRent+"\n");`

Basically my question is how do I access the `String line` from the GUI Class so that I can use `txtArea.setText`to display `line` bearing in mind the GUI has no Main Method?

EDIT:

To try get around this, I have created a `LineObject` which takes `line` in as a parameter. I then call the `getLine` from the `void addComponents` but it gives a nullPointerException?

Here is the searchProps class:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class searchProps 
{
    protected String price, area, query, suburb, date, SaleOrRent, strQuery, out, line="";
    protected int agentID, upid, StreetNum, numBeds, numBaths, numGarages, ownerID, size;
    protected boolean spool;
    PropertyObject PropertyArray[] = new PropertyObject[3];
    LineObject obj;
    JFrame jf;  
    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
     {
        initialFrame();
        addComponents();
    }

public searchProps(int propID) //search using UPID only
   {
       try 
               {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:PropertyOracleDatabase");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();



            query = ("SELECT * FROM Properties WHERE UPID = "+propID);

            // Fetch table
            s.execute(query);
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
            while((rs!=null) && (rs.next()))
            {
                upid=rs.getInt(1);
                StreetNum=rs.getInt(2);
                suburb=rs.getString(3);
                area=rs.getString(4);
                price=rs.getString(5);
                agentID= rs.getInt(6);
                numBeds=rs.getInt(7);
                numBaths=rs.getInt(8);
                spool=rs.getBoolean(9);
                numGarages=rs.getInt(10);
                date=rs.getString(11);
                ownerID=rs.getInt(12);
                SaleOrRent=rs.getString(13);
                size++;


              line = (line+upid+"\t"+StreetNum+"\t"+suburb+"\t"+area+"\t"+price+"\t"+agentID+"\t"+numBeds+"\t"+numBaths+"\t"+spool+"\t"+numGarages+"\t"+date+"\t"+ownerID+"\t"+SaleOrRent+"\n");
              obj= new LineObject(line);
              System.out.println(line);
              String out = obj.getLine();
              System.out.println(out);
            }



            // close and cleanup
            s.close();
            conn.close();
               }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



   }
    void initialFrame()
    {
        jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setSize (1300,700);
        jf.setTitle("Property Oracle | Results Page");
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

     void addComponents()
     {

         Container con = jf.getContentPane();
         con.setLayout(null);
         txtArea.setBounds(20,30,1200,600);
         con.add(txtArea);
         txtArea.setText("UPID\tStreetNum\tSuburb\tArea\tPrice\tAgentID\tBedrooms\tBathrooms\tSwimming Pool\tGarages\tDate\tOwner\tSale/Rent\n");
         out = obj.getLine();
         System.out.println(out);



     }

}
```

And here is the LineObject class:
public class LineObject

```
{
    protected String line;


    public LineObject(String a)
    {
        line = a;
    }


    public String getLine()
    {
        return line;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make it `public` or add an accessor (getter) method. Is it static, or does it belong to an instance of the GUI class?

Comment: The regular way is to create a `getter()` method for `line` in its class. If the other class is in the same package it can access `line` directly after instantiating the object of the class that defines `line`.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your database access code runs in a separate thread, otherwise typical latency would block the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT). Pass a reference to your `JTextArea` as a parameter to your database code. Use the reference to update the `JTextArea` on the EDT:

```
final String line = …
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ta.append(line);
    }
});
```

A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Make `line` a private class field of your class (the one that runs the while loop).

```
public LoopingClass {
  private String line;

  public void loopMethod() {
    line = //...
  }
}
```

Then create a public getter to this variable.

```
public LoopingClass {
  private String line;

  public void loopMethod() {
    line = //...
  }

  public String getLine() {
    return line;
  }
}
```

Then from your GUI, call the getter of the object instance.

```
// somewhere in your GUI class
loopingClassInstance.getLine();
```

Comment: Tried this, however, when called it gives a null pointer exception. Thing is, I trace line and it definitely has data up until it gets called in the void addComponents method.

Comment: To make the whole thing work, you must be sure that the used classes are correctly instanciated (`new LoopingClass` somewhere), then that you can actually access it from the calling class (GUI class), there should be something like `loop = new LoopingClass()` somewhere in the GUI class

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller): it's always good practice to decouple the business logic (putting data in a database and building the string "line") from the frontend (GUI).

By the way, since you're building the string by appending more data to it, you should consider using a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();

// append data:
lineBuilder.append(someString);

// create a string only when you need it:
String line = lineBuilder.toString();
```

In this way you are not continuosly creating new strings (which can be expensive in the long run especially if the string keeps growing), but using the buffer provided by the `StringBuilder` and then creating an actual string only when you need it, e.g., when you need to update your `JTextArea`.