# Sequencing configuration run operations in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have recently switched from Eclipse to NetBeans to develop Swing GUI applications easily. I need to run 2 different configurations in order for my Java sockets implementation (Server, then Client)

Is there a way to simulate execution of these configurations in order using scripting or otherwise within NetBeans (issuing a single command)? I would prefer not to have to select each configuration individually.

Apologies for the trivial question, I'm new to the NetBeans environment.

Thanks.

Comment: but do you want to run the server before the client? You can right-click the projects directly and choose execute.

Comment: Using multiple frames is usually [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513), but you might look at this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513) for testing.