# socket server problems with JLabel

Tags: java, swing, sockets, networking, leaderboard

For quite a while now I have been fighting to create a socket that behaves in the intended way. As an example I have created the following simple swing program to represent the problem.

When ran, a user enters a number into the textfield and presses the post button. A socket is then created and the score (the number entered) gets taken to the server program which performs a method called leaderboard. Depending on the number entered and how many entries are made, a result would be given in the form of a string called rank, which is where my problem begins...

No matter what code I write, what order the code is in, I just cannot get the server to return the string rank and set string rank as the text of JLabel l2 in the client program.

I am very new to socket programming, and I am sure that I have probably missed some important lines. If there is any advice that anyone could give, it would be greatly appreciated, many thank.

### CLIENT CODE:

```
package client;


public class client implements ActionListener {

public static JButton b;
public static JTextField tf;
public static JLabel l2;
String score;

public client(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("SocketServer");

    JPanel bg = new JPanel();
    bg.setBounds(0, 0, 192, 266);
    bg.setBackground(Color.white);
    bg.setLayout(null);

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("ENTER YOUR SCORE HERE:");
    l1.setBounds(10, 20, 172, 20);

    tf = new JTextField();
    tf.setBounds(10, 50, 172, 20);

    l2 = new JLabel();
    l2.setBounds(10, 80, 172, 20);

    b = new JButton("POST SCORE >>");
    b.setBounds(10, 120, 172, 20);
    b.addActionListener(this);

    f.setSize(200, 300);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);

    bg.add(l1);
    bg.add(tf);
    bg.add(l2);
    bg.add(b);
    f.add(bg);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new client();
}

public void initClientSocket(){
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 55555);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.write(score);
        out.close();            
        socket.close();


        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        //System.out.print("Recieved string: '\n"); ///// original and working
        //System.out.print("Recieved string: " + in.readLine() + "'\n"); ///// modified
        //while (!in.ready()) {}
        //l2.setText(in.readLine());
        //in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    if (a.getSource() == b){
        //initClientSocket();
        score = tf.getText();
        tf.setText("");
        initClientSocket();

    }
}
}
```

### SERVER CODE:

```
package server;

class server {

static long scor;
static long s1 = 0;
static long s2 = 0;
static long s3 = 0;
static long s4 = 0;
static long s5 = 0;
static String rank;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Waitng for client to connect.....");
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(55555);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        System.out.print("Client has connected!\n");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String score = (in.readLine());
        scor = Long.parseLong(score);
        leaderboard();
        //in.close();////////////////////

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        System.out.print("Sending rank: " + rank);
        out.print(rank);
        //out.flush();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
        server.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
    }
}

public static void leaderboard(){
    if (scor <= s1){
        if (scor <= s2){
            if (scor <= s3){
                if (scor <= s4){
                    if (scor <= s5){
                        rank = "Too low!";
                        return;
                    }
                    if (scor > s5){
                        s5 = scor;
                        rank = "You rank 5th!";
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (scor > s4){
                    s4 = scor;
                    rank = "You rank 4th!";
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (scor > s3){
                s3 = scor;
                rank = "You rank 3rd!";
                return;
            }
        }
        if (scor > s2){
            s2 = scor;
            rank = "You rank 2nd!";
            return;
        }
    }
    if (scor > s1){
        s1 = scor;
        rank = "You rank 1st!";
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Here's a complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).