# Multiple instance of ONE JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, instance

In Java, I have 2 classes. One contains a JFrame. On startup, that class is called. The JFrame shows.

But in the other class, when I press a button on it's own frame, it opens a *new* instance of that class which should make another frame. But it just focuses on the old frame already opened...

Source:

**FrameToOpen.java**

```
public FrameToOpen() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    // Just the most simple settings to make it appear...
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

**OtherClass.java**

```
public OtherClass() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel window = new JPanel();
    JButton openFrame = new JButton("Open Frame);
    // Again, just the most simple settings to make it appear with components...
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(window);
    window.setLayout(null);

    window.add(openFrame);
    openFrame.setBounds(5, 5, 100, 30);

    openFrame.addActionListener(this);

    frame.repaint();
    frame.validate();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o = e.getSource();
    if (o == openFrame) {
        // THIS HERE MAKES NEW INSTANCE OF FRAMETOOPEN
        new FrameToOpen();
    }
}
```

So, when I press this button, it doesn't open a new frame, but just focuses on old one.

Please help.

**'Actual' Classes**

*ServerGUI.java*

```
    if (o == openAdmin) {
        int port;
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(portNumber.getText().trim());
        } catch(Exception er) {
            appendEvent("Invalid Port Number.");
            return;
        }

        // FrameToOpen.java. Opening a new instance of that class...
        new ClientGUI("localhost", port, true);
    }
```

*ClientGUI.java*

```
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Client");
Dimension d = new Dimension(600, 600);
JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();

public ClientGUI(String host, int port, boolean isHost) {

        this.isHost = isHost;

        frame.setSize(d);
        frame.setMinimumSize(d);
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        // Everything else in the class is my buttons, lists, editor panes,
        // and socket handling...

}
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Swing GUIs might have to work on different platforms, using different PLAFs, on different screen sizes and resolutions with different default settings for font size.  As such, they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) as well as [layout padding and borders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556) for white space.

Comment: I actually read that article JUST before posting this, and I actually couldn't find anything helpful... All I want to do is be able to have two instances of one class at once in the form of a JFrame. (Having two of it open at once)

Comment: Why frame is defined inside the constructor? How do you mantain the reference to that JFrame?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Button creates a new frame every time just fine. This obviously is not your actual code (dummy names and syntax errors). Show us your real code, or a minimal portion of it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The problem (which isn't explained very clearly) seems to be *"but just focuses on old one."*.  That **would not be a problem** if the 2nd 'frame' was in fact a `JDialog` with the actual `JFrame` specified as the owner.

Comment: No, this is my actual code. I actually use frame and window. Will upload actual code. And actually just moved JFrame frame; inside to not need to include whole class...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: ..or perhaps this actually needs a `CardLayout`.  The question seems inconsistent and confusing as to what actual effect is required.

Comment: One frame; two instances, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: @trashgod, how is that relevant sorry...?

Comment: @tobias_k ActionListener... I added an actionlistener to the button. It equals true when the button is pressed. Also I added the 'true' class...

Comment: @Sk4llsRPG Yes, but are you 100% positively sure that the body of the if-clause is executed? Did you put some print statement in there to see? Because in your example code, it will _not_ be executed, because the member variable `openFrame` is _not_ the same button you attach the action listener to.

Comment: Well I don't know whats wrong with that but the button executes fine. It just checks the action listener and converts it to an Object. The second that button is pressed it equals true, so then the if statement kicks in. That is actually the class with the `openFrame` as that part is 100% not edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined your frame variable as being `static`:

```
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Client");
```

so it is created only once for the class, no matter how many instances are created. Remove the `static` modifier if you want to hava it as an instance field.

Comment: OMG. You know what... That actually just worked... 0_0