# Why adding element to JList makes it empty in this particular case?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

As the title says, when i try to dynamically add an element to a `JList`, which is inside a `JScrollPane`, it becomes empty. I think it has something to do with multithreading.

The GUI is a simple monitoring interface for a server I am working on. I'll post parts of the code I think is responsable for this:

But first, this is the frame:

```
public class EventMonitor extends JFrame{

private JList eventList;
private DefaultListModel<String> dlm ;
JScrollPane jPane;

public EventMonitor()
{
    super("Server Monitor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    dlm = new DefaultListModel<String> ();

    eventList = new JList();
    jPane = new JScrollPane(eventList);
    jPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(950, 600));
    add(jPane);

}

public void addEvent(String event)
 {
    dlm.addElement(event);
    eventList.setModel(dlm);
    jPane.revalidate();
    jPane.repaint();

 }
}
```

In `main()` from `Server` class:

```
     //some code
    eventMonitor = new EventMonitor();
    eventMonitor.setBounds(250, 250, 1000, 650);
    eventMonitor.setVisible(true);
     //some other code
    eventMonitor.addEvent("Server is waiting for new connections..."); // this is shown in the list
    while(true)
        {
            ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(listener.accept());// listener is ServerSocket
            clientList.add(clientHandler);
            clientHandler.start();
        }
```

This is what makes the list go empty: in`ClientHandler` constructor:

```
public ClientHandler(Socket socket){
//some code
Server.addEvent("The client is: " + user.GetName() + ", with the ip:" + user.GetIPv4() + ", and using the port: "  + user.GetPORT());
//some more code 
} // where Server.addEvent(String event) just calls eventMonitor.addEvent(event)
```

After this, `'run`' from `'ClientHandler'` listens for messages and they are posted via `Server.addEvent()`, and it works without a problem, but when another client connects it goes empty again. The first event shown after the one in `ClientHandler` constructor makes the list whole (showing the event that made it empty too)

Comment: 1- Swing is not thread safe and the call to `dlm.addElement(event);` should be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, wrapping in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` should help. 2- There should be no need for `eventList.setModel(dlm);`, `jPane.revalidate();`, `jPane.repaint();` within the `addEvent` method

Comment: For further reading I recommend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: @keuleJ I'll read that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're blocking the UI thread in the loop - when you call `accept()`, that's going to wait for a new connection, which means the UI thread can't repaint the UI. You should do that in a separate thread.

All *UI* interactions should be performed in the UI thread though, e.g. using [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: I will try that and I'll post an update after. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @laurGanta: A related example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).