# How can i get my program to reply with an answer

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I'm working on a program that you can have a conversation with so I could ask it hello and it would reply.

But when typing in the text field I can't seem to get it to display the answer in the other text field.

here is my code so far any help is useful

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTextField input, output;

    private String answer;
    private JPanel contentpanel;
    boolean opchosen = false;

    public Gui() {
        super("Vixen");
        input = new JTextField(null, 20);
        output = new JTextField(null, 20);

        question q = new question();

        input.addActionListener(q);

        contentpanel = new JPanel();
        contentpanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        contentpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        contentpanel.add(input, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        input.setEditable(true);

        contentpanel.add(output, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        output.setEditable(false);

        this.setContentPane(contentpanel);
    }

    private class question implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event) {
            JTextField input = (JTextField) Event.getSource();
            if (input.equals("whats you name")) {
                if (opchosen == false) {
                    if (answer == null) {
                        answer = "My name is Vixen!";
                    }
                }
            }

            if (opchosen == false) {
                output.setText(answer);
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Okay that problem is fixed but when i try to ask another question my output box wont display the new answer its just stuck on My name is Vixen

Comment: Have you debugged into your code?  What specific line(s) are causing you problems?

Comment: From what I can tell by visually parsing your code It will only respond to the input `whats your name`. Also you should use `input.getText().equals(...)` instead of `input.equals(...)`.

Comment: you put - whats you name, not, whats your name

Comment: Lupz thanks what you suggested works

Comment: Okay now when i try to allow another question it doesnt change the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use your `JTextField` for input only. In the text field's `actionPerformed()` implementation, `append()` the input text and the response to an adjacent `JTextArea`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513) illustrated the basic approach. In the example, responses come from another socket; yours will come from code that handles canned responses.