# TCP with Swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, tcp

I'm doing a simple chat application with `TCP` in java.

In my code i have add a GUI but with some reasons it doesn't work even i have connected to server.

I can't figure out what is the problem.

I run the GUI and it works.

Hope that someone can help.

**Server:**

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3);
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            String str;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
            while(true){
                str = "Connected to server";
                bw.write(str);
                bw.newLine();
                str = br.readLine();
                bw.write(str);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Client1 implements MouseListener {
    private JFrame jF;
    private JTextArea area;
    private JTextField field;
    private JButton send;
    String str;
    BufferedReader br;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    private Socket client;
    public Client1(){
        try {
            client = new Socket("localhost", 3);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
            str = br.readLine();

            jF = new JFrame("Simple Chat");
            jF.setSize(500, 500);
            jF.setLayout(null);
            jF.setResizable(true);
            jF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            area = new JTextArea();
            area.append(str);
            area.setLocation(0, 0);
            area.setSize(500,400);
            jF.add(area);

            field = new JTextField();
            field.setLocation(0,400);
            field.setSize(400,100);
            jF.add(field);

            send = new JButton("Send");
            send.setLocation(400, 400);
            send.setSize(100,100);
            send.addMouseListener(this);
            jF.add(send);

            jF.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client1();
    }
}
```

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

Comment: @trashgod i'm thinking about 2 client connected to 1 server, chat with each other. I'm not sure how can i update the textarea in each client to not appear their own chat twice. That's my problem now .

Comment: where did you override mouselistener methods? if you click "send" it should connect to server and update your text area with socket's outputstream right?

Comment: Swing is a single threaded frame work, your call to `br.readLine` will block the EDT potentially preventing it from updating the UI in any, meaningful manner.  You're also think in a very procedural manner, where as GUIs are event driven environments.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details