# Java Swing simple chat frame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I am writing a simple chat. While I do my project in IntellijIdea I found it a bit complicated (GUI designer), and then I did the frame that I need in NetBeans. It looks fine, but when I resize this window, some elements (`chatArea` and `messageArea`) become bigger (which is fine), but on scaling down, they save their 'bigger size'(but I need them to scale down). How can I fix scaling?

Code generated:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    chatArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    messageArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    listOnline = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    buttonDeselect = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    buttonSend = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("SDChat3");
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 500));

    jScrollPane1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    chatArea.setColumns(20);
    chatArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    chatArea.setLineWrap(true);
    chatArea.setRows(5);
    chatArea.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 300));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(chatArea);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    messageArea.setColumns(20);
    messageArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    messageArea.setLineWrap(true);
    messageArea.setRows(5);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(messageArea)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(messageArea, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jScrollPane3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    listOnline.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    listOnline.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane3.setViewportView(listOnline);

    buttonDeselect.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    buttonDeselect.setText("Deselect");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
    jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
    jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane3)
        .addComponent(buttonDeselect, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 377, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(buttonDeselect, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    buttonSend.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    buttonSend.setText("Send");
    buttonSend.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonSendActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(buttonSend, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 201, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(buttonSend, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void buttonSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton buttonDeselect;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonSend;
private javax.swing.JTextArea chatArea;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
private javax.swing.JList<String> listOnline;
private javax.swing.JTextArea messageArea;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: One solution is simple: don't use GroupLayout and instead use layouts that you have much more direct control over. The [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) can help you with this.

Comment: It looks to me like a disaster, NetBeans and IntellijIdea designers both too complicated, when I do something on the form it always unpredictable to me. Seems like I'm trying to play chess without pawns...

Comment: 1) *"Please, help me to do this window!"* Ignoring that there is no actual question, see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: You may get some ideas from this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).